# How can you continue the for loop in R even after an error?

Tags: r, for-loop, error-handling, rvest

I am parsing data from multiple links. But some of those links got broken after a while. And when I parse using `rvest` package it shows an error or warning. What can I do to continue parsing with for-loop, so it moves to the next line.

```r
house_link <- "https://somon.tj/adv/7985721_2-komn-dom-grandzavod/"
house_features = data.frame()

for(x in 1:length(house_link)) {
  
   tryCatch({
      page_data = read_html(house_link[x])
      message("Executed.")
  }, error = function(e){
      message('Caught an error!')
      print(e)
  }, warning = function(w){
      message('Caught an warning!')
      print(w)
  }, finally = {
      message('All done, quitting.')
  }
)    
    pricing = page_data %>% html_nodes(".css-13sm4s4") %>% 
      html_element("span") %>% html_text() 
    house_features = rbind(house_features, data.frame(pricing, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
}
```

Comment: I did, Nad Pat--This is simplified version of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
library(rvest)

house_link <- "https://lalafo.kg/bishkek/ads/104-seria-2-komnaty-47-kv-m-s-mebelu-kondicioner-zivotnye-ne-prozivali-id-95221626"
house_features = data.frame()

for(x in 1:3) { # seq_along(house_link)  <- if you have more than 1 link this is the correct method
  
  cat('Link', x)
  
  start_time <- Sys.time()
  if (x %% 200 == 0) {
    Sys.sleep(5)
    print("pausing ...")}
  
  page_data <- tryCatch({
    page_data = read_html(house_link[x])
    message("Executed.")
  }, error = function(e){
    message('\nCaught an error!')
    return(NA) # here a return variable for testing is returned in the error condition - notice that this has to be initiated with the return function
  }, finally = {cat('Continuing with', x+1,'\n')})   #; next()})  <-  disabled next()
  
  ## This part is handled by finally next()
  ############################
  if(is.na(page_data)){      #
    cat('this is a test\n')  #
    next()                   #
    }                        #
  ############################
  
  else{  # else is not strictly necessary but the point may be easier to contextualised like this
    pricing = page_data %>% html_nodes(".css-13sm4s4") %>% 
      html_element("span") %>% html_text() 
    house_features = rbind(house_features, data.frame(pricing, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  }
}

Link 1
Caught an error!
Continuing with 2 
this is a test

Link 2
Caught an error!
Continuing with 3 
this is a test

Link 3
Caught an error!
Continuing with 4 
this is a test
```

Comment: Dear D.J. When I run the code in my machine, it doesn't go pricing and below. This is my understanding that the code perhaps loops around `tryCatch()` because the data frame `house_features` is empty. I am sorry I am quite new to R.

Comment: it is not supposed top go to pricing... you only give us one link which does not work. you can test it if you delete the `;next()` part from the fionally command - it will then go straigt to pricing (which of course fails). else this works just fine - you can test this by changing `seq_along(house_link)` to `1:3` and adding a `print()/cat()` message after your tryCatch - ill update the answer accordingly

Comment: I don't quite understand--D.J.--why it shows 'Error in if (is.na(page_data)) { : argument is of length zero' :(

Comment: i cant replicate your error. is it possible you forgot to add the `return(NA)` function in your error message?

Comment: I simply copy pasted for double checking. And revised only the input data to be more than one link, you know. 
@D.J I am really struggling to handle errors in R. It's indeed confusing for newcomers.

`Link 1Executed.
Continuing with 2 
Error in if (is.na(page_data)) { : argument is of length zero`

Comment: ok run the loop manually piece by piece and check the results of every step. as it works just fine for me it is very difficult to troubleshoot.. for some reasons it seems  `page_data` doesnt get generated for you. no idea why. if this problem keeps up maybe make a new question with your exact code (inkluding all the links) and show the error messages

Comment: That's a brilliant idea. Thanks for your reply, D.J :)